# Is it possible to prevent testcafe/hammerhead scripts injection in specific iframe?

Tags: testing, iframe, automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

everyone.
What I want to do - to create an **empty/pristine** iframe on testcafe page.

Problem:
Testcafe/hammerhead injects custom script, that overrides prototypes and creates many global variables. I need to prevent it somehow. So I need to create iframe on testcafe page, but without all this custom injected stuff.[image]

Is there any API method or "hack" for this?

I use the latest testcafe version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestCafe cannot operate with an iframe without embedding service scripts.
I agree that making a global variable is not the best practice in JavaScript.
However, TestCafe's global variable is marked as non-enumerable (see [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/blob/8797f891d8ca8620eb2f393ef44f735cfe05ec88/src/client/index.ts#L240)). It means that the client's script cannot find this global variable because it cannot access it without knowing this variable's name.
In my opinion, the prototype overriding is not a big problem because a lot of JavaScript frameworks (Angular, JQuery, etc.) do the same.

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer. But I dont need Testcafe to operate iframe. I want to avoid it :))
At all.

Comment: Currently, TestCafe does not provide any option to prevent injecting the script into the iframe.